# selecting records based on results from the same page

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not even sure if this is possible but it feels like it should be...

I have 3 tables.

The first generates a product code and holds some basic information about that product.

I need to be able reference other records from that table to be 'sub' ingredients to a product code. e.g. product 00001 is made up from product 00002 and 00003 etc.

ProductCodes:

```
id     name    medium
00001  test1   Other 
00002  test2   Raw
00003  test3   Raw
00004  test4   Other
00005  test5   Raw
00006  test6   Raw
```

Products are marked as Raw if they can be used as 'sub' ingredients for the 'master' product.

My current method is to use the second table to reference the 'sub' ingredients codes along with the 'master' product, e.g.
IngredientProductList:

```
id|BACode      |IngredientBACode  |Percentage
__________________________
1 |00001     |00002               |90
2 |00001     |00003               |5
3 |00004     |00002               |80
4 |00004     |00006               |20
```

The third table holds percentage information which could potentially be included in the second table if necessary.

I've tried inner joins but I can't see how to base the join on the result of the first sql query.

```
$BACode=$_GET['BACode'];

// Attempt select query execution
$sql = "SELECT ProductCodes.id , ProductCodes.Supplier , ProductCodes.suppliers_code , ProductCodes.item_name , ProductIngredientList.BACode , ProductIngredientList.IngredientBACode , IngredientsList.BACode , IngredientsList.IngredientType , IngredientsList.IngredientName
FROM ProductCodes
LEFT JOIN ProductIngredientList ON ProductIngredientList.BACode = ProductCodes.id
LEFT JOIN IngredientsList ON IngredientsList.BACode = ProductIngredientList.IngredientBACode
WHERE ProductCodes.id = '$BACode'
```

I can't see the wood for the trees at the moment but I can't move on to the next step until I know that this works or, alternatively make all the changes necessary to find a work around.

I am trying to produce a page that has the product information as a heading and then the ingredints listed in percentage order as well as other information which can be added later. I am just not sure if I have the tables set up correctly and what type of query I should be using to access the data.
Thanks for any help.

IngredientsList:

```
id |BACode |IngredientType |IngredientName |Allergen |FreeFromArtificalColours
51 |13582  |flour          |               |No       |Yes
53 |13583  |flour          |               |No       |Yes
54 |15386  |Modified       |               |No       |Yes
```

Desired Layout :

```
BACode: BA0001 Item Name:test 

Ingredients: BA0002 Allergen Information
             BA0003 Allergen Information
```

**New code following advice

```
// create connection 
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password") 
or die("Couldn't make connection 1."); 

// select database 
$db = mysql_select_db("database", $connection) 
or die("Couldn't select database 1."); 

$BACode=$_GET['BACode'];
?>
<div class="box" id="settlement1">
        <?
            $query  = "SELECT * FROM ProductCodes WHERE id = '$BACode'";
            $result = mysql_query($query);

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                $item_name = $row['item_name'];
                $medium = $row['medium'];

            }
        ?>
        <div class="settlement-name">
          <? echo "
            <table border=1 width=700>
                <tr>
                        <th>Product Name </th>
                        <th>Product Code</th>
                        <th>Medium</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td>$item_name</td>
                        <td>$BACode</td>
                        <td>$medium</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <th>14. Ingredient Name </th>
                        <th>Percentage</th>
                        <th>Country Of Origin</th>
                </tr>
         " ?>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="box" id="settlement2">
        <?
            $query  = "SELECT ProductIngredientList.id, ProductIngredientList.BACode, ProductIngredientList.IngredientBACode, ProductIngredientList.Percentage, ProductIngredientList.RecipeVolume, ProductCodes.id, ProductCodes.item_name, ProductCodes.COO 
            FROM ProductIngredientList 
            LEFT JOIN ProductCodes ON ProductIngredientList.BACode = ProductCodes.id
            WHERE ProductIngredientList.BACode = '$BACode'
            ORDER BY ProductIngredientList.Percentage";

            $result = mysql_query($query);

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
            {
                $IngredientBACode = $row['IngredientBACode'];
                $item_name = $row['ProductCodes.item_name'];
                $Percentage = $row['Percentage'];
                $COO = $row['ProductCodes.COO'];

            echo "


                <tr>
                        <td>$IngredientBACode $item_name</td>
                        <td>$Percentage</td>
                        <td>$COO</td>
                </tr>


            ";
            }

            echo "</table>";
        ?>
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: you forgot to mention what goes wrong with your query, or what result you actually expected from it. And you forgot to show us the IngredientsList table.

Comment: @ADyson I have just not been able to get the information I want to be returned. Is it possible to have a second query on the same page based on the results of the first  query from the same table? e.g. query 1 results in multiple IngredientBACode results from the ProductIngredientsList and then to run a query to get the relevant results from the ProductCodes table based on the BACodes?

Comment: yes of course you can. Anything is possible, in theory. You can run as many queries as you like, and you can use data from earlier queries as parameters in the later ones. Then again it might be possible to do it all in one query - if, as I already requested, you give us a concrete example of what you actually want to see, and complete the set of sample data, we can probably help you.

Comment: @ADyson I've edited to show third table and potential basic layout. Thanks for looking, any help is appreciated

Comment: where are the percentage values you mentioned? And is there always just one entry in IngredientsList for each BACode? What primary and foreign keys are defined on your tables?

Comment: @ADyson In IngredientsList there will only be one entry per BACode. There is a id field in each table which is a Primary Key. The percentage values are stored in ProductIngredientList and will just be used to order the sub ingredients in descending order.

Comment: yes but what do the percentages look like? What's the field called? You didn't show it in your example, yet it's needed for your query. Also, if there's only ever one entry per BACode in IngredientsList, why do you need a separate table for it? Why can't those fields just exist in ProductCodes, which is where the code originates from?

Comment: @ADyson I've amended the table to show the Percentage column. This was originally set up to have different codes for the Raw ingredients so I just hadn't changed it so it could combine the two tables. Thanks

Comment: so the simplest suggestion is to select all the "Other" products from ProductCodes. Then use PHP to loop through the results. Within the loop, first print the info about the product. Then write a query to select all records from IngredientProductList where the BACode equals the id of the Product the loop is currently reading from, and order it by percentage. Inner Join it to IngredientsList on IngredientProductList.IngredientBACode = IngredientsList.BACode to get the allergen info. Then start another loop to go through this second set of results and print them.

Comment: This will have the effect of going through each of your main products, and running a secondary query to get the ingredients just for that product, and listing them in the correct order. So if you have 10 products, you will end up running 11 queries (one query to get the products, and 10 queries to get the ingredients).

Comment: @ADyson Thank you, that makes more sense. I think I'd made myself dizzy with all of the options and loops! Thanks again, Kate

Comment: @ADyson Can I just check that the above code is what you meant? I'm having problems displaying the records from ProductCodes from the inner join but I'm hoping that's just a syntax error somewhere!

Comment: I would have thought your second query needs to be an INNER join (not a LEFT join) from ProductIngredientsList to IngredientsList, as I suggested. Right now you're joining back to ProductCodes, which won't get you any of the allergy information you said you wanted. What does "having trouble" mean though? If you had a SQL syntax error, your code would crash. You aren't checking whether your query is ok($result will be `false` if it fails, and `mysql_error()` returns the error message - see http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php). If you had a PHP syntax error, it wouldn't run at all.

Comment: Also, why are you using the long-deprecated `mysql_` code library? It was discontinued many years ago and removed entirely in PHP7. No new code should be written using this library. It leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (due to the lack of parameterised query support) and potentially other unpatched vulnerabilities. Switch to using `mysqli` or `PDO` as soon as possible, and then learn how to write parameterised queries to protect your data from malicious input. See http://bobby-tables.com for a simple explanation of the risks and some sample PHP code to write queries safely.

Comment: @ADyson It's been a number of years since I did anything like this and I've been asked by the comapny I used to work for to make some changes to an old system so I'm quite rusty and very much out of the loop with changes to PHP etc. Thanks for the pointers - I'll start looking at updating what I've already got before making any further issues.

Answer (score 0):

Foreign keys is your answer. You want to reference a product in the sub-product table, then create another table in the IngredientProductList, like ProductID, which references the original ID in the Product table.

Comment: I have two colums in the sub-product table 'IngredientProductList' which lists the Original Product code and references the 'sub' products. I'll look into foreign keys.

Comment: If you have found my answer to be what you need, please vote and mark as Answered. Thanks